# how can I bring the 2 cards in a row in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

in desktop view 2 cards are appearing in a row,i also want them to appear in a row in mobile view.I used col-sm-4.but it's not making it happened. What should i do to bring the cards in a row  in mobile view.so i can see the product photo and details at the same time without scrolling.

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">

<div id="product_details_info">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h3 class="h2-title">Product Details</h3>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card h-100 card-body border-0 shadow">
              <img class=" shadow d-block w-100" style="object-fit: none;height:450px; " src="{{asset('img/electrical.jpg')}}" alt="First slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 py-3" id="order_now_section">
          <div class="card h-100 border-0 shadow">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center;">
                <h3 class="product-title" style="font-family: 'Piedra', cursive;font-size:35px;text-align:center">men's shoes fashion</h3>

                <h5 class="quantity" style="font-family: 'Sriracha', cursive;">quantity</h5>

                <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-warning" style="width: 50%;margin:auto;text-align:center;" min="0">

                <h5 class="" style="font-family: 'Sriracha', cursive; padding-top:20px;">price</h5>
                <h5 class="" style="font-family: 'Sriracha', cursive;padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">100 BDT</h5>
                <div class="action">
                  <a href="{{URL::to('/products/product_details')}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="font-weight:bold;"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>&nbsp Order Now </a>

                  <a href="{{URL::to('/products/product_details')}}" type="button" id="heart_id" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="font-weight:bold;"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span> </a>

                  <h3 class="product-title" style="font-family: 'Piedra', cursive;font-size:20px;padding-top:20px;text-align:center">Product Details</h3>
                  <p class="product-description" style="font-family:  'Raleway', sans-serif;">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! </p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you include col-xs-4 it should work for mobile devices (<576px)